What is "Hyper-V Hypervisor" in Windows 11 Pro?
I'm talking about this thing here:

I've read the older questions here and they explain the other features nicely, but this one seems to be new or something. I also can't figure out what Google keywords to use to find out more info about this.
What confuses me is that I'm currently running virtual machines through both VirtualBox and Hyper-V without any problem. And I don't even have either "Virtual Machine Platform" or "Windows Hypervisor Platform" installed. What's this thing for then? And on a side note - what's the "Hyper-V Services"?

Update: As per comment request, here's a slightly anonymized screenshot of my system (I have a dual-monitor setup; click to enlarge):

In addition to that, here's System Information which shows that Virtualization-based Security is running:

Now, my question is - how in the world is this working if Hyper-V is not installed? What even does the "Hyper-V Hyperision" option mean then?

It’s absolutely not new, it’s been around for a decade, Hyper-V is Microsoft’s hypervisor. What’s clear is the optional features were moved around in the list. I assume your using 23H2 or 24H2?

@Ramhound 23H2. What surprises me then is that it's not installed, but still working.

What exactly is working? VirtualBox working without Hyper-V installed is expected

@Ramhound Hyper-V too. Like, I have working a virtual machine under Hyper-V Manager. Also VirtualBox shows the "turtle" icon indicating that it's going through Hyper-V. Plus there was something about Windows 11 enabling it by default for some sort of security features. It was possible to disable them by jumping through some hoops, but I've not done that. So all evidence points at Hyper-V being installed and enabled - yet in this here dialog it's unchecked.

can you put up a screenshot of hyper-v manager and the running vm?  Also, the turtle in VBox just means it can't access hardware virtualization.  Many things on Win11 can cause this, not just the Hyper-V role.

@Vilx - Your question only mentions VirtualBox. “Plus there was something about Windows 11 enabling it by default for some sort of security features.” - Hyper-V is not enabled by default

@Ramhound Updated my question with more screenshots to clarify.
